# Shared memory Vectors in boost with

Tags: boost, vector, shared-memory

I have the following code. Trying to have a shared memory vector with structure having string and arrays. But when i compile the code I am getting error:

```
 usr/local/include/boost/container/vector.hpp:1819:4: error: no matching function for call to ‘InData::InData(InData* const&)’
```

Any suggestion how to fix this. I am new to Boost.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <boost/interprocess/ipc/message_queue.hpp>
#include <boost/scoped_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/shared_memory_object.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/mapped_region.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/allocators/allocator.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/string.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/vector.hpp>

using namespace boost::interprocess;

typedef boost::interprocess::basic_string<char> shared_string;

    struct InData
    {
        int X,Y,H,W;
        shared_string Label;
    };

    int main()
    {

        shared_memory_object::remove("MySharedMemory");
        managed_shared_memory managed_shm(create_only, "MySharedMemory", 10000);

        InData tData;// = managed_shm.construct<InData>("InDataStructure")();

        tData.Label = "Hello World";
        tData.H = 1;
        tData.W = 1;
        tData.Y = 1;
        tData.X = 1;

        typedef allocator<InData,managed_shared_memory::segment_manager> tStructData;
        typedef vector<InData,tStructData>  MyVector;

        //Initialize shared memory STL-compatible allocator
         tStructData alloc_inst (managed_shm.get_segment_manager());

         //Construct a vector named "MyVector" in shared memory with argument alloc_inst
          MyVector *myvector = managed_shm.construct<MyVector>("MyVector")(alloc_inst);

          //InData data;
          myvector->push_back(&tData);

        return 0;
    }
```

If just do `myvector->push_back(tData)`

```
/usr/local/include/boost/container/detail/advanced_insert_int.hpp:166:10: error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘InData’ and ‘const value_type {aka const InData}’)
```

Comment: Come on guys, this is fine question. Everything is there. It's not a "debug my code for me" question.

Answer (score 1):

I've live-coded my review: **[recorded session](https://www.livecoding.tv/video/fixing-the-allocator-mess-q33531339/)**

The fixed up code is below. Some of the notes (please watch the streaming session, though):

1. you failed to give the "shared" string an allocator. That means it uses `std::allocator` and the allocations are done from the program heap. OOOPS. Your program will die, if you're lucky.
2. once you give the `shared_string` the proper allocator, you'll find ripple effects. You need to pass in allocator instances at construction of `shared_string` because interprocess allocator instances are **not** default constructible.

   > Rule Of Thumb: Stateful allocators are painful. If you avoid the pain, you're doing it wrong (and allocating from the wrong heap)
3. naming is important:

   ```
   typedef allocator<InData, managed_shared_memory::segment_manager> tStructData;
   ```

   why name your allocator type `tStructData`? You might as well call it `XXX`. So, change it to

   ```
   typedef allocator<InData, managed_shared_memory::segment_manager> salloc;
   ```

   > *This took me while while I was trying to make sense of your code...*
4. Instead of explicitly creating `alloc_inst`, considering using the implicit conversion from `segment_manager`
5. The line

   ```
   myvector->push_back(&tData);
   ```

   tries to push a *pointer* into a vector of class objects. That can never work, regardless of your allocator(s)

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/10000376928990e2)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/interprocess/shared_memory_object.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/allocators/allocator.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/string.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/vector.hpp>

using namespace boost::interprocess;

struct InData;
typedef allocator<InData, managed_shared_memory::segment_manager> salloc;

typedef boost::interprocess::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, salloc::rebind<char>::other> shared_string;

struct InData {
    int X, Y, H, W;

    InData(salloc alloc) : Label(alloc) {}

    shared_string Label;
};

int main() {

    shared_memory_object::remove("MySharedMemory");
    managed_shared_memory managed_shm(create_only, "MySharedMemory", 10000);

    // Initialize shared memory STL-compatible allocator
    salloc alloc_inst(managed_shm.get_segment_manager());

    InData tData(alloc_inst); // = managed_shm.construct<InData>("InDataStructure")();

    tData.Label = "Hello World";
    tData.H = 1;
    tData.W = 1;
    tData.Y = 1;
    tData.X = 1;

    // Construct a vector named "MyVector" in shared memory with argument alloc_inst
    typedef vector<InData, salloc> MyVector;
    MyVector *myvector = managed_shm.construct<MyVector>("MyVector")(alloc_inst);

    // InData data;
    myvector->push_back(tData);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But I still get the second error I mentioned about:  error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘InData’ and ‘const value_type {aka const InData}’)

Comment: Please share the ***exact*** code you used this time. You can clearly see I don't get that with my code (and with 2 compilers, and 2 different standard library implementations)

Comment: I used exact code you have changed and still get the error.

Comment: Also, how can I add dynamic arrays to the structure like float*

Comment: @Mrutyunjay compiler/library versions? Dynamic arrays: `vector<T, alloc>`

Comment: Boost version is 1.59.0

Comment: Sigh. I'll wait for the rest

Comment: Could you please more details about how to create dynamic array?

Comment: Exactly the same as the `shared_string`. But with `vector`.

Comment: Yes tried but getting errors as "error: no matching function for call to ‘boost::interprocess::allocator<boost::container::container_detail::list_node<float, boost::interprocess::offset_ptr<void>......."    Also Tried: typedef boost::interprocess::list<float, salloc::rebind<float>::other> shared_float;

Comment: Time for a new question. This amount of detail is useless and comments are not for helpdesking

Comment: @sehe Can you read the elements off the vector, without needing to pass in the segment manager?

Comment: @user997112 Yes. Accessing elements doesn't allocate. The interface also doesn't accept allocators for that reason, see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at and http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at