# boost::interprocess : Creating and inserting elements to a vector of structs (C++03)

Tags: c++, boost, c++03, interprocess

I have problem with creating vector of complex structures within boost::interprocess using msvc2008. Answers of questions asked before (links below) provides some solutions, but none of them works with msvc2008. Error type is always the same:

```
error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘complex_data’ and ‘const complex_data’)
```

Previous questions about the problem:

[Shared memory Vectors in boost with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33531339/shared-memory-vectors-in-boost-with)

[How to I create a boost interprocess vector of interprocess containers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26280041/how-to-i-create-a-boost-interprocess-vector-of-interprocess-containers)

Suggested solutions:

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/10000376928990e2

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3d6582c2d59015d2

Note: I know I should move to newer versions of Visual Studio. But sadly, I am currently stuck with msvc2008.

Comment: You should consider to upgrade to a more recent tool.

Comment: You don't say? (Nicholas Cage meme is staring at you sarcastically).
Just joking, one our vital tools is not upgradable. So I am kind of stuck with that at the moment.

Comment: So you're stuck with Visual Studio 2008 ??

Comment: Yeah, the tool (a library we can say) we are talking about is compiled with msvc2008. So I should compile my project with msvc2008 compiler.

Comment: OK, you should specify that in your question. And there is no way you cat get compiled that library with modern tools?

Comment: This is the current situation I can say. There is a newer version of it (with C++11), but buying it is beyond my control. So to continiue doing what I do right now I need to do it with msvc2008. Thank you for your suggestion, I will specify that.

Comment: Just a thought: the people who decide if a modern devtool should be bought should consider the time you spend searching a solution vs. the cost of a modern devtool + additional benefits of the modern tool..

Comment: Can you show the actual code you're trying to compile?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your actual code, it looks as if you should perhaps add `operator=` for your type because MSVC is not able to generate it (?).

```
//Other members...
complex_data& operator=(complex_data const&) = default;
```

Or if the compiler doesn't take that hint, define the body the old-fashioned way:

```
complex_data& operator=(complex_data const& rhs) {
    id_ = rhs.id_;
    char_string_ = rhs.char_string_;
    int_vector_ = rhs.int_vector_;
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: You can consider first suggested solution I gave in the question is the exact code I am trying to compile. Actually, I think this is great because it is your solution. But i see that you say you cannot reproduce the error.

Comment: This is strange, are you trying to compile with Visual Studio 2008?

Comment: I didn't say I couldn't reproduce it. I will not try to. I can look at the code sample and imagine what hints MSVC would require - which is my answer. Your comment confuses me because the ["first suggested solution \[you\] gave in the question"](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/10000376928990e2) doesn't even contain the type referred to in the error message.