# Clang error: use 'template' keyword to treat X as a dependent template name

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, clang

I'm using Clang 3.4.2. Whilst looking at a solution provided here:

[Shared memory Vectors in boost with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33531339/shared-memory-vectors-in-boost-with)

The line:

```
typedef basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, salloc::rebind<char>::other> shared_string;
```

gives me the error:

```
error: use 'template' keyword to treat 'rebind' as a dependent template name
    typedef basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, salloc::rebind<char>::other> shared_string;
```

I tried:

```
typedef basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, salloc::template rebind<char>::other> shared_string;
```

and even:

```
typedef basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, template salloc::rebind<char>::other> shared_string;
```

but I still get the error.

Could someone please help correct me in my ways?

Comment: It should be `salloc::rebind<char>::other` (as written at that linked answer)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I did think that, but the person answering knows his stuff.

Comment: @VTT I still get the same error after correcting that

Comment: `salloc::template rebind<char>::other`.

Comment: @songyuanyao also required "typename" before it, but thanks

Comment: You should provide [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) then. Because at the current form there are no dependent types here and neither `template` or `typename` are required.